# get aws session token expiry time

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

we are in a world where we can run an opaque tool that gives us aws session tokens - ie in ~/.aws - there's a file with access_key, secret access key, session token.

Trouble is when we use them - they just expire at unpredictable times.

Is there any way, from just that information - to figure out *when* the token is going to expire?   Or an aws cli command that tells you when the current session token will expire?

Comment: It is better to get new session token when it is expired

Comment: `aws sts assume-role` returns that info when you run the command to assume a role. Not sure if you can get expiration time in any other case.

Comment: trouble is - our code just works assuming there is a token out there - when it's running in any deployed environment something else is taking care of that - and when we are running locally - there's an opaque enterprise ssl  tool I have to run to refresh the tokens - so bottom line - I can't _get_ the token myself... I just "have' the token.